# How can I check which port mule is running in?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I deploy my app using mule in Windows and I want to check which port mule is running. I tried to run mule-debugger in IntelliJ and got a `Unable to open debugger port ... Connection refused` error, so I'm trying to find out if I have configured the incorrect port for mule.

Answer (score 0):

Open debug configuration and change port, i generally use some crazy port beyond 10k.

Also "Run as administrator" is preferred, i fall into some random issues with default user rights

[image]